# How to use Dev Console to search for User?

Tags: developer-console

I'm in a new org that has 600+ Approval Processes and hundreds of custom approval processes that's a custom object.

Is there a way to just input "John Smith" in the Dev console and see everything affiliated with that user? & then I can just comb through it from there.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that kind of search in the Dev Console. You'll need to use an IDE, such as VS Code. Note that because of the various types of configuration, you'll have to search by user name and User Id to find all instances of the user.

Comment: Thanks Fox. Always a pleasure